# Magento 1.9.2.2 use SQL expression in addFieldToFilter

Tags: mysql, supee-6788, ce-1.9.2.2

I'm using Shop by Brand extension by Magestore guys and it stopped working when I upgraded to 1.9.2.2. I investigated the issue and found out the problem was with new security patch. So I've investigated more and figured out that in [`APPSEC-1063, addressing possible SQL injection`](http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) Magento guys explained that the following code:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('(field1-field2)', array('eq'=>3));
```

Should be changed to:

```
$expression = '(field1-field2)';
$condition = $this->_getConditionSql($expression, array('eq'=>3));
$this->_select->where(condition);
```

So we can't use SQL expressions as a direct parameter of `addFieldToFilter` anymore.

In the extension, there's this piece of code:

```
// Magestore_Shopbybrand_Model_Mysql4_Brand_Collection:153
return parent::addFieldToFilter("IF(brand_$field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, brand_$field.value)", $condition);
```

So the problem is right here because when I changed the code to following it works:

```
return parent::addFieldToFilter("main_table.$field", $condition);
```

Yeah, I know I should open a ticket about this (and I will) but I was curious how can I fix something like this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer that produced the module? It's up to them to provide secure, proper SQL syntax that doesn't open up SQL injection issues. Which was the purpose of the patch. Most developers have been pretty responsive to fixing these issues.

Answer (score 4):

not sure if this will work, but you can try to use `addExpressionFieldToSelect` and then `having` on the expression you use.

Something like

```
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
    'expression_alias',
    '{{field1}} - {{field2}}',
    array('field1' => 'real_field1_name', 'field2' => 'real_field2_name')
);
```

and then

```
$collection->getSelect()->having('expression_alias >= 3');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for Magestore_Shopbybrand module :

```
$expression = "IF(brand_$field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, brand_$field.value)";
$conditionSql = $this->_getConditionSql($expression, $condition);
$this->getSelect()->where($conditionSql);
return $this;
```